# Powershell script to change the Recycling Time on Application Pool

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I found the code that I think that i need to use, but the thing is that it is not working.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$appPools = Get-childItem 'IIS:\AppPools\App Pool'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $appPools -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 1.00:00:00
```

But I am getting this error

```
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.NodeCollection' because it does not exist.
At line:3 char:1
+ Set-ItemProperty -Path $appPools -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 1.0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\SysW....NodeCollection:String) [Set-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
```

I know it isn't a path issue.  This does work.

```
set-itemproperty -path 'D:\test\TestPS\New Text.txt' -name IsReadOnly -value $true
```

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* a path issue.

The object returned from `Get-ChildItem 'IIS:\AppPools\App Pool'` is a `NodeCollection` object, and when you run `Set-ItemProperty -Path $appPools`, `$appPools` is expanded to "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.NodeCollection" (which is not a valid path)

To change the properties of the app pool:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\AppPools\App Pool' -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 1.00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias.  Ok, I see that it is working and it is changing the Regular Time Interval.  I would like to change the Specific Time to say 1AM.  Do you know what the -Name recycling. would be?